# How to split large merge request into parts in git

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-branch

I have developed a feature which needed small changes around in 30+ files.
Now I want to send the merge request but reviewer can't review more than 10 files in single request.
How can I split this merge request in 3 different requests for his convenience??

My Efforts:
One way of doing this is to create new branch, pull everything from old branch and handpick files and
git add git commit and git push them,

Is there any better way of doing this ??

Comment: When you say "can't review more than 10 files in single request", do you mean "can't, "prefers not to", or "won't"? Note that splitting the code into multiple merge requests could possibly leave the code in an unstable state prior to the entire thing getting completed, unless you take steps to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Also, if you split the merge request into separate commits of smaller parts, it may be easier to review by commits rather than all files at once.

Comment: Thanks. by "Can't" I meant "won't".  
I solved it by cherry picking the commits and sending individual merge requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create new  branch here, please follow the below to handle this situation:

- First tell you reviewer to Abandon your commit in gerrit.
- Run git status; if you get output like Your branch is ahead of 'branch_name' by 1 commit. then Run "git reset --soft HEAD~1"
- Run git gui; it will open a UI interface.
- un-stage 20 files and close the GUI.
- Run git status and you will see some files are in red(un-staged file) and green(staged file. ready to commit) color.
- Run git commit -m"commit_message"
- Run git push

FOLLOW THE SAME PROCEDURE TO COMMIT REST OF THE FILES.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/splitting-pull-request for future references.